# Build SOAP request using generated proxy classes without xml tag or with encoding utf-8 instead of utf-16

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap, xmlwriter

I want to write request to soap service.
I have wsdl file. Using svcutil I've generated proxy clasess for that request.
In result of it, I request with correct parameters but the request contains xml tag on start of it with encoding utf-16.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

Seems like this isn't supported by endpoint to which I'm doing request. So question - can I somehow change encoding or remove that xml tag at all?

I've found that `XMLWriter` has `XmlWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration`. So when it is true, xml tag shouldn't appear in request. But don't know how to add/change XmlWriter for generated soap client.

when creating soap client I can only set `Binding` and `endpoint`

```
public outbClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
        base(binding, remoteAddress)
{
}
```

Comment: How are you actually serializing your classes to XML? I'm going to guess it's using a `StringWriter`? That's the usual cause of a declaration with `encoding="utf-16"`

Comment: @canton7, you are right. it is StringWriter. The problem it isn't my writer, so cannot change its behaviour whith what I have...

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3248) seems relevant. There's what looks like a workaround at the bottom